# Error in Aerospike while accessing secondary index AEROSPIKE_ERR_INDEX_NOT_READABLE

Tags: aerospike

Aerospike is throwing AEROSPIKE_ERR_INDEX_NOT_READABLE error when I try to access the secondary indexes. Created index using below syntax

CREATE INDEX index_id ON test.class (id) STRING;

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restarting Aerospike I am able to use the newly created index.

Answer (score 3):

```
aql> create index id1 on ns1.testset (1) string;
OK, 1 index added.

aql> show indexes
+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
| ns    | bin | indextype | set       | state | indexname | path | type     |
+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
| "ns1" | "1" | "NONE"    | "testset" | "WO"  | "id1"     | "1"  | "STRING" |
+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
[127.0.0.1:3000] 1 row in set (0.001 secs)

+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
| ns    | bin | indextype | set       | state | indexname | path | type     |
+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
| "ns1" | "1" | "NONE"    | "testset" | "WO"  | "id1"     | "1"  | "STRING" |
+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
[172.14.10.12:3000] 1 row in set (0.002 secs)

OK

aql> show indexes
+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
| ns    | bin | indextype | set       | state | indexname | path | type     |
+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
| "ns1" | "1" | "NONE"    | "testset" | "RW"  | "id1"     | "1"  | "STRING" |
+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
[127.0.0.1:3000] 1 row in set (0.001 secs)

+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
| ns    | bin | indextype | set       | state | indexname | path | type     |
+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
| "ns1" | "1" | "NONE"    | "testset" | "RW"  | "id1"     | "1"  | "STRING" |
+-------+-----+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+------+----------+
[172.14.10.12:3000] 1 row in set (0.002 secs)

OK
```

Note: 1) don't need the semicolon when creating index but it won't throw error.  So:

```
aql> create index id1 on ns1.testset (1) string
```

would be the right way. 
2) Once you issue the command to create the index, depending on the data size, takes time to build the SI. Check state:  WO --> Index is not readable yet but you can insert records and they will be indexed. When state becomes "RW" - read/write - you can do SI queries.
You shouldn't have to restart Aerospike server.

Comment: After creating index I waited for one day, but no use index is still in "WO" state after restarting it rebuild the index and then state turned to "RW" state.